# Swift: Change object with property in array

Tags: swift

I am trying to amend an object in my AnyObject (savedProgram). I want to save  Taking the advice from another thread, I've used 'as!' to convert it to [AnyObject]:

```
    @IBAction func saveM(sender: UIButton) {
    brain.variableValues["M"] = displayValue
    savedProgram = brain.program as! [AnyObject]
    var indexValue = savedProgram?.indexOfObject("M")
    savedProgram?[indexValue!] = displayValue
```

It complains at the 4th row. I've also tried changing the original variable savedProgram to [AnyObject] but then I am not sure how to look up "M" and amend it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is in the 4th row?

Comment: savedProgram?[indexValue!] = displayValue, where it says cannot assign immutable expression of type anyobject